# Macro to Check Value in Range of Interval

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define CHECK(x,y,n) (x > 0 && x < n && y > 0 && y < n ? 1 : 0))
int main(void)
{
/*char s[5];
int i;
strcpy(s,"abcd");
i = 0;
putchar(s[++i]);*/
int i = CHECK(2,3,10);
    printf("%d",i);
  return 0;
}
```

I want to declare a macro to check if two values x and y are in the interval but when I try to compile and build, I get these errors from the compiler:

```
line 4 error: expected ',' or ';' before ';' ')' token
```

Comment: extra closing parentheses in the end of the macro i guess

Comment: or, missing parenthesis before start of ternary operator.

Comment: @SouravGhosh there is always another way to look at a problem..  ;)

Comment: you won't need `? 1 : 0` to get 1 and 0

Comment: if you are using `gcc`, gnu extension is a great help in defining macro by using `({ ... })` to define a block returns value.

Comment: @haris Agree, in general. but in this case, a parenthesis can change the whole meaning. consider the current version and `....y < (n ? 1 : 0)`) version.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: If you're using gcc (or any other modern compiler) you could make this a static function which is almost certain to be inlined (or even constant-folded). There is almost no excuse for macros like this in this century.

Comment: @rici well, it's a suggestion to solve the question in given context. actually i won't put too much trust on what "modern" compiler is capable of. I would put `__attribute__((pure))` if i need to define it to be a static function in gcc. and even in 21st century, there are conditions that macro is the only choice.

Answer (score 2):

There is an extra `)` in the macro. Any way, I would suggest to enclose all of the macro arguments in parentheses to avoid problems with precedence and some other macro pitfalls:

```
 #define CHECK(x,y,n) ((x) > 0 && (x) < (n) && (y) > 0 && (y) < (n) ? 1 : 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, don't!

A function is almost always better that a macro:

- type checking and better compiler warnings
- almost always just a fast
- more readable
- easier to debug, add trace-point
- probably works better with your IDE

If you want, you can make it static, to keep the name private.
If you want, you can make it static inline, to allow it in header files.

Answer (score 0):

```
   #define CHECK(x,y,n) (x > 0 && x < n && y > 0 && y < n ? 1 : 0))
                                                                 ^extra ')'
```

Answer (score 0):

the core of the problem is the macro 'check'

Here is a corrected version of the program, with comments

```
#include <stdio.h>
// #include <stdbool.h> // not needed for posted code
// #include <ctype.h>   // not needed for posted code

// notice the parens around the condition
// notice the end of the action part of the macro only has
//        a single paren, to match the opening paren
//        at the beginning of the action part of the macro
#define CHECK(x,y,n) ( (x > 0 && x < n && y > 0 && y < n) ? 1 : 0)

int main(void)
{
    /*char s[5];
    int i;
    strcpy(s,"abcd");
    i = 0;
    putchar(s[++i]);*/

    int i = CHECK(2,3,10);
    printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

the result compiles cleanly and performs the desired action

notice the appropriate code indentation

```
indent after every opening brace '{'
un-indent before every closing brace '}'
```

Comment: the code will work without the parens that I added, but is much less readable and the reader needs to know that '?:' has a lower priority than  '&&' to fully understand it.   I.E. the parens I added make it much clearer as to what is being performed